# IdentityServer4 Getting Claims using Reference Token with Client_Credentials

Tags: c#, .net-core, identityserver4

I have an identity server implementation that works perfectively with jwt tokens and two different clients that access it.

- Mr Console authenticates using client_credentials
- Ms Website authenticates using pkce

In both cases when using jwt tokens I can get the claims with only one issue. The size of the token is getting out of hand and we'd like to use reference tokens instead.
I changed the token type from Jwt to Reference and can now get the claims for Ms Website by calling the user info endpoint and passing in the reference token. Great!

The problem I have is that I cannot seem to get the claims for Mr Console.

- I cannot call the user info endpoint because it expects a user and throws an error "Token contains no sub claim" - which it wouldn't as I'm using client credentials.
- I cannot call the introspective endpoint as it appears to only be available to internal apis and fails with the error "API unauthorized to call introspection endpoint".

How can I get the claims from within my client console application when provided with a reference token and not a jwt? Is there a way?

Thanks

Comment: Client creds are supposed to be used for machine to machine, with no user context considered. How many claims do you have ?

Comment: For client credentials we don't have a lot so could switch back to jwt but I'd ideally like to know how/why it works anyway. It seems strange that I can use reference tokens but then not call an endpoint to get the information related to that reference token e.g. expiry, audiences etc - as well as client claims if defined

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using the client credentials flow you have no user claims available.

However you have [Client claims](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/fundamentals/claims/#client-claims) that you can use instead, have you considered to use those instead of userclaims?

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail
about this topic: [Debugging OpenID Connect claim problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/03/28/missing-openid-connect-claims-in-asp-net-core/)